# Foreign keys in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have a method for inserting in database.

I have 1:n relationship between the tables `Point` (n) and `Line` (1). `Point` has foreign key `idLine`.

However, the class `Point` in Entity Framework doesn't have the `idLine` property.

Now, in my method I have object of type `Point`, as parameter and here I have a problem because I don't know to what to assign the `idSection` of the new `Point` object which is inserted in the table.

How to add the `idLine` property in the `Point` class?

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5? Are you using EntityObject based entities?

Comment: Are you using "code first", or do you have an EDMX file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using `EF4.0`, since this is not possible in previous version (`EF1.0` does not include foreigh key properties in model).

In your generation wizard you need to make sure that "Include foreign key columns in the model" checkbox is checked when you're generating data model. Otherwise foreign key columns will be omitted when generating data.

If I'm remembering correctly you cannot simply add forign keys to classes that are already generated. You would need to manually edit all the mappings (not impossible, might be little bit troublesome if you are new to EF). Or you can simply remove this class from design area and add it again (making sure appropriate checkbox is checked this time). This might be simpler if you haven't customized generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

add a foreign key in your model like following :-

```
public int? LineId { get; set; }
public virtual LineId LineId {get; set; } // this for one to one
```