# Entity framework get the foreign key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 1:n relationship between to tables in a database: Employee (1) : Role (n)
Role has foreignKey named idEmployee

I want to create a linq statement which will get every role for a given customer. I want to make something like this:

```
var myQuery = from r in Role 
              where r.idEmployee == someId
              select r;
```

But, r doesn't have an idEmployee property! How can I get the value of the foreign key?

Comment: Make sure that u create the relation properly and refresh your entity framework model (diagram) then it will appear

Comment: What column(s) are in the foreign key?

Comment: @AMgdy The relationship is ok and I refresh it. Nothing.

Comment: Which **version** of Entity Framework are you using?? EF in .NET 3.5 did not surface the foreign keys at all - EF 4.0 allows you to do so - but it's an option you have to check when creating the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `EF4.0` at least, this will give you what you need: [Foreign keys in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643933/foreign-keys-in-entity-framework/8644254#8644254)

If you're using `EF1.0`, your problem is more serious since it does not show foreign keys in model. You need to iterate through `EntityKey.EntityKeyValues` collection in search of valid value. But I think this would only get you value of foreign key and would not work in query (since EF would not know how to translate it to SQL query).

But since you have foreign keys, why don't you simply use `NavigationProperty` to navigate to `Employee` entity and check value there?

```
var myQuery = from r in Role 
              where r.Employee.idEmployee == someId
              select r;
```

Comment: But sometimes r.Employee is null although the employee has idEmployee in the table. How to resolve this?

Comment: Well, if `r.Employee` is null this means that `Role` is not assigned to any `Employee`, assuming you have set Foreign Keys on database correctly. If that's the case, then your `Role` object would have `idEmployee` set to `null`. There is no other way. You can check your data base schema to see if `Role` table allows null on column referencing `Employee` table.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using EF 4.0 (.NET 4.0), and a database-first programming model with an EDMX model (visual designer), then you need to make sure to have the option `Include foreign key columns in the model` checked when you add tables to your EDMX model:

[image]

If you don't have this option checked, then EF 4.0 will behave the same as EF 1.0/3.5 (in .NET 3.5) which is to include a navigation property - but **not** the foreign key column as a separate column.

Answer (score 0):

Use the include method on Employee class to bring back all the related roles:

```
var myQuery = from e in Employees.Include(emp => emp.Roles)
              where e.EmployeeId == someId
              select e
```